# My Webview in fragment always refresh when i switch my tab from one to other

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I want to save instant of my fragment and then restore back on reopening the tab. when switching from one tab to other.
here is my fragment code:

```
package com.mhm.universityofwah.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.mhm.universityofwah.R;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.Objects;

import jp.co.recruit_lifestyle.android.widget.WaveSwipeRefreshLayout;

public class WebFragment extends Fragment implements WaveSwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private WaveSwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private Activity context;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setRetainInstance(true);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avicenna, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (WaveSwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener((WaveSwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener) WebFragment.this);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView=view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListner);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            loadWebsite();
        }
        return view;
    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListner=
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_refresh:
                            mWebView.reload();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_back:
                            if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
                                mWebView.goBack();
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_forward:
                            if(mWebView.canGoForward()){
                                mWebView.goForward();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void loadWebsite() {
        ConnectivityManager cm  = (ConnectivityManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert cm != null;
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://uow.edu.pk");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Network Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Network Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }else if (url.contains("mailto:")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mWebView.reload();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NotNull Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        // here your code
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
    }
}
```

I have 4 tabs but when i switch from one tab to other and come back to first one, it always reload. i tried every thing but my problem is not solved. Please help me to get this thing done.

Comment: What do you mean by a reload? Do you mean the state is not restored?

Comment: Yes exactly. Everything time i switch back to fragments the webview alwas start from initial and destory previous view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setRetainInstance(true);

 if(view == null){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avicenna, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (WaveSwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener((WaveSwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener) WebFragment.this);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView=view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListner);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        loadWebsite();
    }
  }
    return view;
}
```

please make view a global variable and add null check when your onCreate view recalls it recreates the view so add check that if view != null then only return already initialized view instead of creating again

Comment: i have tried this put the problem is same. its not working. Here i didn't understand ""so add check that if view != null then only return already initialized view"" Please can you elaborate?

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avicenna, container, false); this line recreates the view again and again , whenever you come back to your fragment from another fragment or from background onCreateView calls again and again thus View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avicenna, container, false); this line executes again and  again which is why your webviews recreates itself just put a check there if view is already initialized then only return view instead of re initializing it again , i hope you understand